# Range partation

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with following structure,

```
CREATE TABLE test_range_partition (
    table_name   VARCHAR2(30),
    order_date   DATE,
    num_rows     NUMBER
) PARTITION BY RANGE(num_rows) (
    PARTITION num_rows1 VALUES LESS THAN (100) TABLESPACE part1,
    PARTITION num_rows2 VALUES LESS THAN (1000) TABLESPACE part2,
    PARTITION num_rows3 VALUES LESS THAN (10000) TABLESPACE part3,
    PARTITION num_rows4 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) TABLESPACE part4
);
```

If I want to select data

```
select * from test_range_partition where num_rows =100
```

which partition is selected?

Comment: `num_rows2` according to the logic.

Answer (score 0):

- num_rows1  contain 1 to 99
- num_rows2  contain 100 to 999
- num_rows1  contain 1000 to 9999 and so on 
  So your answer is num_rows2